# MATLAB R2015a segmentation fault with selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering

Tags: opengl, matlab

My OS release is 14.04

When I launch MATLAB with GUI, I got the response with

```
MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

There is nothing in the log of `matlab_crash_dump.1582-1`

But with `matlab -nodisplay`, it worked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @edwinksl Thanks for your answer! But I can't find the conversation between us, i don't know why.

Comment: The problem is still there. I can't find a solution for that.

Comment: I removed my answer because it turns out that it didn't solve your problem. We can continue talking about this in chat to avoid protracted comments.

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a bug. See [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/861205/308164).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:  here is how I fixed it.  I had switch from the open source nouveau driver that come preloaded on ubuntu to the proprietary nVidia version 361.42.  I then got the error you did. It turns out that matlab is not compatible with the newest version of the nVidia driver yet.  So I downgraded the driver to the proprietary version of the driver 340.96. The driver packages are in the additional drivers tab of Software & Updates.

I then reinstalled matlab and installed the matlab-support package(code below).

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

Good luck!

Comment: I had suggested the OP to try that but that unfortunately didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I had to downgrade my Nvidia driver to an earlier version,  reinstall Matlab,  and then install the support package.

Comment: You should include that in your answer since downgrading a graphics driver is an important detail.

Comment: Can do. He doesn't specify what graphics driver he is using.

Comment: Yeah, you should ask the OP for that.

Answer (score 1):

After trial and error, I find this problem is caused by two files:

```
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6.0.22
```

Find them by searching in you `/usr/lib` folder, copy and paste them in the folder with overwrite:
`.../MATLAB/sys/os/glnxa64`, then restart `matlab` and it will work.

I think my system is compiled by a more advanced compiler than that of matlab, thus this problem happening. Hope it helps.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. See [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/861205/308164)