# Matlab no longer runs in Ubuntu (due to installing openjdk?)

Tags: java, matlab

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and after having installed some packages over the weekend Matlab 2016a does no longer run and crashes on startup. Importantly, I installed openjdk-8-jre (because other software depended on it - e.g. some Python modules that were also installed), which I suspect to cause problems for Matlab (that run without issues before the last weekend). Having reinstalled Matlab did not solve the problem. From my internet recherche thus far it seems like Matlab is very specific about the Java environment. Have Unfortunately I don't have much expertice with Java and which version is used on my opterating system and thus could not resolve the issue so far. Have I, with the installation of openjdk-8-jre changed some settings in Ubuntu such that Matlab now can now longer find it's required Java environment? How can I make Matlab run again? Thanks!

Here's the log Matlab created at crash time:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Mon Nov 28 11:38:26 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Current Visual      : 0x20 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.23 stable
  Host Name           : notebook-nb
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /opt/matlab/R2016a
  MATLAB Version      : 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11804000), display :0

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 0000000000000000  RBX = 00007f6dc833a0e8
  RCX = 00007f6de022eb20  RDX = 0000000000000006
  RSP = 00007f6e693a6ce0  RBP = 00007f6e693a6e00
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007f6dc83108a8

   R8 = 0000000000000030   R9 = 0000000000000004
  R10 = 00007f6dc8690ef0  R11 = 00007f6dc830d000
  R12 = 00007f6df444cd80  R13 = 0000006900000006
  R14 = 0000000000000006  R15 = 00007f6dc8311280

  RIP = 00007f6e84c2856c  EFL = 0000000000010206

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f6e84c2856c                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00050540
[  1] 0x00007f6e84c31681                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00087681
[  2] 0x00007f6e84c2c394                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066452
[  3] 0x00007f6e84c30bd9                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00084953
[  4] 0x00007f6e82399f09                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00003849
[  5] 0x00007f6e84c2c394                        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+00066452
[  6] 0x00007f6e8239a571                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00005489
[  7] 0x00007f6e82399fa1                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2+00004001 dlopen+00000049
[  8] 0x00007f6e7ebe50b6            /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00315574
[  9] 0x00007f6e7ebe5c76            /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00318582 _Z11utGetModuleRKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEPi+00000022
[ 10] 0x00007f6e7ebe5d6b            /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libut.so+00318827 utGetModule+00000171
[ 11] 0x00007f6e7370bd45 /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00482629
[ 12] 0x00007f6e736feeaf /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00429743 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn8try_loadEv+00000031
[ 13] 0x00007f6e736f5e95 /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00392853 _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn4loadEv+00000037
[ 14] 0x00007f6e736f35e9 /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_dispatcher.so+00382441 _ZN13Mfh_MATLAB_fn11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000057
[ 15] 0x00007f6e707381c9       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+09232841
[ 16] 0x00007f6e70864dbf       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10464703
[ 17] 0x00007f6e7085aa5a       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10422874
[ 18] 0x00007f6e70823911       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+10197265
[ 19] 0x00007f6e702f1b2a       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04750122
[ 20] 0x00007f6e702f2a4c       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04753996
[ 21] 0x00007f6e702f0ebc       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746940
[ 22] 0x00007f6e702ee9ea       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04737514
[ 23] 0x00007f6e702eedb1       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04738481
[ 24] 0x00007f6e702f0a63       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04745827
[ 25] 0x00007f6e702f0be9       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+04746217
[ 26] 0x00007f6e703a116f       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05468527
[ 27] 0x00007f6e703a422a       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+05481002
[ 28] 0x00007f6e70646543       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08242499
[ 29] 0x00007f6e7060f07e       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08015998
[ 30] 0x00007f6e70613058       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08032344
[ 31] 0x00007f6e70613107       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08032519
[ 32] 0x00007f6e7068932c       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08516396
[ 33] 0x00007f6e7068970c       /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_lxe.so+08517388
[ 34] 0x00007f6e7310cd7d /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwm_interpreter.so+03165565 _Z51inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnInDesiredWSAndPublishEventsRKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEPibbP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000077
[ 35] 0x00007f6e73d859e1         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00825825 _ZNK3iqm18InternalEvalPlugin24inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnERKSbIDsSt11char_traitsIDsESaIDsEEP15inWorkSpace_tag+00000081
[ 36] 0x00007f6e73d85b58         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00826200 _ZN3iqm18InternalEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000120
[ 37] 0x00007f6e5160dee4     /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+00974564 _ZN9nativejmi21JmiInternalEvalPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000340
[ 38] 0x00007f6e51633edd     /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libnativejmi.so+01130205 _ZN3mcr3mvm27McrSwappingIqmPluginAdapterIN9nativejmi21JmiInternalEvalPluginEE7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000429
[ 39] 0x00007f6e73d78f98         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00774040
[ 40] 0x00007f6e73d62c87         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00683143
[ 41] 0x00007f6e72bda7a9      /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00173993
[ 42] 0x00007f6e72bdac44      /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00175172
[ 43] 0x00007f6e72be11a5      /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00201125
[ 44] 0x00007f6e72be12ac      /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00201388
[ 45] 0x00007f6e72be197b      /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwbridge.so+00203131 _Z8mnParserv+00000715
[ 46] 0x00007f6e73a35c13         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00695315
[ 47] 0x00007f6e845be81c         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so+02410524 _ZNK5boost9function0IvEclEv+00000028
[ 48] 0x00007f6e73a37925         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00702757
[ 49] 0x00007f6e73a38839         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00706617 _ZN5boost6detail17task_shared_stateINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvRKNS_8functionIFvvEEEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIS6_EEEEEEvE6do_runEv+00000025
[ 50] 0x00007f6e7f15f8a0          /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwms.so+03168416 _ZN5boost6detail22task_base_shared_stateIvE3runEv+00000064
[ 51] 0x00007f6e73a39717         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00710423
[ 52] 0x00007f6e73a3575a         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00694106
[ 53] 0x00007f6e73da8c06         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00969734
[ 54] 0x00007f6e73d96b4c         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00895820 _ZN5boost6detail8function21function_obj_invoker0ISt8functionIFNS_3anyEvEES4_E6invokeERNS1_15function_bufferE+00000028
[ 55] 0x00007f6e73d9721f         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00897567 _ZNK5boost9function0INS_3anyEEclEv+00000031
[ 56] 0x00007f6e73d96993         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00895379 _ZN3iqm18PackagedTaskPlugin7executeEP15inWorkSpace_tagRN5boost10shared_ptrIN14cmddistributor17IIPCompletedEventEEE+00000163
[ 57] 0x00007f6e73a4a71d         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00780061
[ 58] 0x00007f6e73d78f98         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00774040
[ 59] 0x00007f6e73d635af         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00685487
[ 60] 0x00007f6e73d607e3         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwiqm.so+00673763
[ 61] 0x00007f6e83f7ba3a    /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03443258
[ 62] 0x00007f6e83f7a8a7    /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03438759
[ 63] 0x00007f6e83f7b10c    /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so+03440908 _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00000092
[ 64] 0x00007f6e73a35ed2         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00696018
[ 65] 0x00007f6e73a36211         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00696849
[ 66] 0x00007f6e73a22cfd         /opt/matlab/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmcr.so+00617725
[ 67] 0x00007f6e82b6f70a              /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+00030474
[ 68] 0x00007f6e828a582d                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+01075245 clone+00000109
[ 69] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is a [bug in Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1297894).

That page suggests the following workaround:

1. Find the location where MATLAB is installed (probably `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a`)
2. Navigate to the `sys/os/glnxa64` directory within this folder
3. Rename libstdc++.so.6 library to libstdc++.so.6.old

This forces MATLAB to load the newer version of the `libstdc++.so` library available in Ubuntu (which currently seems to be version 21). Notice that the aforementioned post says they have only tried version 20, so this might not work.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to run MATLAB R2016 in Ubuntu 16.04.02.